# How to set a field of a struct type on an object in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, reflection, boxing, fieldinfo

I am having trouble setting a field on an object in a Windows Phone 7 app (I suspect it's related to the compact framework, and not specific to Windows Phone 7).  I believe this is specific to setting values that are of `struct` types.  Normally I use the following:

```
// fieldName is the name of the field I'm interested in setting
FieldInfo fieldInfo = target.GetType().GetField(fieldName);

// target is the object I'm setting the value on
// value is the value that I am setting
fieldInfo.SetValueDirect(__makeref(target), value);
```

Unfortunately `SetValueDirect` doesn't exist on Windows Phone 7, and simply using `SetValue` doesn't do anything to target.  Is there an alternative way to set `struct` fields on WP7 through reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to box the struct, use SetValue, **and unbox**. Not very elegant, but another good reason that structs should generally be read-only. Currently you are presumably omitting the last step (by using an implicit box without capturing the box, do your change to the boxed value is discarded). Visually:

```
MyStruct val = ...
object boxedVal = val;
fieldInfo.SetValue(boxedVal, newValue);
val = (MyStruct)boxedVal;
```

More generally, meta-programming is rather weak on CF. If you are doing lots of this, there are ways to do the meta-programming *in advance* via full .NET, inspecting a CF assembly and generating a CF assembly that encapsulates the functionality you need. I've had success using IKVM.Reflection for this purpose (th inbuilt .NET reflection *cannot* do this).